# Skirting is too wide for mitre box

Tags: woodworking, tools, renovation

I'm fitting 138mm skirting through a house. I can only find a mitre box  100mm high, or a clamping mitre box (where the timber lies horizontally) 120mm wide.

How can i cut the joints for of the skirting?

Comment: Make yourself a larger mitre box.

Comment: I would cheat and use a drop saw,  these are much more expensive than a mitre box though.

Comment: What's your optional cost of trimming an entire house with a $5 miter box for a week, instead of a $100 miter saw in two days?

Answer (score 2):

Use the mitre box to guide the saw but make the cut outside the box.

- Clamp the box to a table.
- Place a board at least as thick as the bottom of the mitre box behind the box. Clamp it to the table or just hold it against the box while working.
- Place the material to be cut on the board and hold it against the
  mitre box.
- Use a saw long enough to reach across the mitre box + work + cutting
  stroke.

EDIT: This is the correct answer to the wrong question. OP is asking about cutting material that is too *high* for the mitre box; this answer is good for material that is too *wide* for the box.

So the analogue of my technique for op's too-high material would be to clamp a spacer under the mitre box to raise its top to 140mm above the table, hold the material tightly against the box, and cut part-way through the material.

The cut can be finished off by placing the material inside the mitre box as usual.

Comment: I was scratching my head for a moment as I have used a 12” miter saw or radial arm for decades but this advice might work as long as the op keeps the material tight , I might dissemble the box and put a wider center piece in so both ends of the blade are supported like solar mike suggested but if going slow or a saw with a thick rib on the back it might work.